# Designing Angular custom form validations (multiple fields) generated by ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I would like some feedback on improving/designing custom form validations(multiple fields) the Angular way.

I have some form input fields that are generated by `ngRepeat`. Basically, the next input must be greater than the the previous. I called these fields `beginLevel`.

My current implementation is as follow: 
I am using `ngBlur` to call a controller function. 
This function loops through my model comparing the `index[i].beginsAtLevel` 
with `index[i-1].beginsAtLevel`. In the event that the current beginsAtLevel is less than that the previous beginsAtLevel I grab the id of the `form-group` e.g.

`previousIndex = angular.element(document.querySelector('#beginsAtLevel' + (i - 1)));` and

`currentIndex = angular.element(document.querySelector('#beginsAtLevel' + i));`.

I subsequently, add the `has-error` class to the input fields.

`previousIndex.addClass('has-error');`
`currentIndex.addClass('has-error');`

I also have another function `removeErrors()`, which loops through my model and removes the `has-error` class.

This approach works but I feel its a bit of a hack. How could I implement/improve this using a directive? I have seen plenty of examples online that validate only one input at a time.

Here is my function for reference:

```
function validateTiersBeginLevel(tiers) {
    var previous, current, previousIndex, currentIndex;

    for (var i = 1; i < tiers.length; i++) {
        previous = tiers[i - 1].beginsAtLevel;
        current = tiers[i].beginsAtLevel;

        if (Number(current) <= Number(previous)) {

            previousIndex =
                angular.element(document.querySelector('#beginsAtLevel' + (i - 1)));
            currentIndex =
                angular.element(document.querySelector('#beginsAtLevel' + i));
            previousIndex.addClass('has-error');
            currentIndex.addClass('has-error');
        } else {
            clearErrors(tiers);
        }
    }
}
```

as well as my input field(s) generated by `ngRepeat`:

```
<div class="form-group" 
    ng-class="{'has-error': tierForm.beginsAtLevel{{$index}}.$touched &&  
        tierForm.beginsAtLevel{{$index}}.$invalid}" 
        id="beginsAtLevel{{$index}}">
    <p class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">Begin Level</p>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8">
        <input type="text"
            class="form-control" 
            name="beginsAtLevel{{$index}}" 
            ng-model="tier.beginsAtLevel" 
            ng-blur="rp.validateTiersBeginLevel(tiers);" 
            required>
        <div class="text-danger" 
            ng-messages="tierForm['beginsAtLevel'+ $index].$error" 
            ng-if="tierForm['beginsAtLevel'+ $index].$touched">
            <span ng-message="required">Begin Level is required</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The name="beginsAtLevel{{$index}}" will not come out like you expect. Try name="beginsAtLevel[$index]". Also, since it's an ng-repeat, the ng-model you have is going to be the same for each repeat, so that also needs altering similarly: ng-model="tier.beginsAtLevel[$index]"

Comment: I have to disagree with you. The current setup works flawlessly. I have encountered a similar problem where ng-model is the same for all fields. If I am not mistaken I think track by $index does the trick.